# Understanding trig equality

Tags: trigonometry

I was working on a math question and I was wondering if this is true

$$\csc(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)} = \sin^{-1}(x) = \arcsin(x)$$

Thanks.

Comment: No. $\sin^{-1}(x)$ generally denotes $\arcsin(x),$ which is certainly not the same thing as $1/\sin(x)$.

Comment: Nope. $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is a special case of notation where the exponent $-1$ doesn't indicate multiplicative inverse but composition inverse.

Comment: No. Unfortunately, the notation $(\cdot)^{-1}$ can mean two **very different** things: The *reciprocal* and the *inverse function*. Here, cosecans is the reciprocal, but arcsin is the inverse of sin.

Comment: Ah. Thanks mates!

Comment: Most times, nearly all in fact, $(\cdot)^{-1}$ will mean the inverse.  Unfortunately I can't say it will never mean the reciprical.

Answer (score 1):

This is false, but I can see where you got it from. In short:

$$\sin^{-1}(x)=y\to x=\sin(y)$$

$$\csc(x)=y\to \frac{1}{\sin(x)}=y\to x=\sin^{-1}(\frac1y)$$

While in most cases, raising a function to the power $-1$ means flipping it onto the denominator, here $\sin^{-1}(x)$ represents the *inverse* of $\sin(x)$, as opposed to the *reciprocal*. In a lot of basic cases, they mean the same thing, but here they don't.

Comment: "In a lot of basic cases"? Can you show three examples for $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$? (The inverse of the linear function $x\mapsto ax$ happens to be $x\mapsto \frac{1}{a}x$, which might actually be where the unfortunate notation comes from, but even there $f^{-1}(x) \neq \frac{1}{f(x)}$.)

Comment: I'm talking about linear expressions such as $x^{-1}\to\frac 1x$. I know that $f(x)=x\not\to f^{-1}(x)=\frac1x$, but that's exactly the difference my answer is explaining...

Comment: Then could you please clarify that in your post? Because the way it is stated, to me "they" (which "mean the same thing") stands for "the inverse and the reciprocal"; whereas what you seem to mean is "the notations $(\cdot)^{-1}$ and $\frac{1}{(\cdot)}$" often mean the same thing, *namely the reciprocal*, but the first one also has a different meaning, *namely the inverse function*.

Answer (score 1):

Pretend notation wasn't invented.

$\frac 1{\sin x}$ (no matter what notation is given) a different concept than "for a given $x$ find the angle $\theta$ so that $\sin \theta = x$" (no matter what we call) and these values are basically unrelated.  And if we had any doubt we'd just have to try a few examples to get that this is ... absurd.

($\sin 60 = \frac {\sqrt 2}3$ and so $\frac 1{\sin 60} = \frac 3{\sqrt 2}$.  So... if $\sin \theta = 60$ [which is absurd and impossible; $\sin \theta < 1$] then $\theta = \frac 3{\sqrt 2}$????  That's just nutty.  It makes zero sense.  Zero sense at all.)

Then it becomes an unhappy ill thought out occurence that we frequently take $f^k(x)$ to mean "raise $f(x)$ to the $k$-th power" (if we aren't using to mean, instead "take the $k$-th derivative of $f(x)$").  And we take $f^{-1}(x)$ to mean "the inverse of $f(x)$ " i.e.  "For $x$ find the value of $w$ so that $f(w) = x$".

This leads to $f^{-1}(x)$ being ambiguous.  You will almost *never* see $f^{-1}(x)$ to mean $\frac 1{f(x)}$ but you might see in $f^{-3}(x)$ to mean $(\frac 1{f(x)})^3$.  Is this consistent and unambiguous?  Not in the least.  It's ambiguous and quite frankly a mess.

However, it's worth noting that if you ever see $\sin^{-1} x$, it will almost certainly mean $\arcsin x$.... unless it doesn't....  I can't say you'll never see it to mean $\frac 1{\sin x}$.  You might.  I hope not but it could happen.

What can I say but.... sorry?

Comment: I won't say enough times that $\sin^{-1}$ is an *abusive* notation for the inverse of a function *different* from the sine function which obviously has no inverse.

Comment: I hear you.  But I'm afraid it'd be a losing battle.